# Multithread GAE servlets to handle concurrent users

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, servlets

I'd like to multithread my GAE servlets so that the same servlet on the same instance can handle up to 10 (on frontend instance I *believe* the max # threads is 10) concurrent requests from different users at the same time, timeslicing between each of them.

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpServlet {
    private Executor executor;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if(executor == null) {
            ThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestFactory();
            executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPoolthreadFactory);
        }

        MyResult result = executor.submit(new MyTask(request));

        writeResponseAndReturn(response, result);
    }
}
```

So basically when GAE starts up, the first time it gets a request to this servlet, an `Executor` is created and then saved. Then each new servlet request uses that executor to spawn a new thread. Obviously everything inside `MyTask` must be thread-safe.

What I'm concerned about is whether or not this truly does what I'm hoping it does. That is, *does this code create a non-blocking servlet that can handle multiple requests from multiple users at the same time*? If not, why and what do I need to do to fix it? And, in general, is there anything else that a GAE maestro can spot that is dead wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 - I really like the way you are thinking about the problem and the way you tried to approach a solution. But (un-)fortunately GAE doesn't work this way and the `currentRequestThreadFactory()` method doesn't quite do what one might expect based on how you can read its name. I posted an answer below that hopefully clears up the ambiguity in the method name. (It's currentRequest-Thread-Factory, not current-RequestThread-Factory) ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there anything specific you are trying to achieve? I'm asking, because a little while back, I was looking into the exact same question. I was hoping to implement some sort of long-polling push notifications using GAE, but it turned out that there are many other additional issues that will get in your way with something like that. GAE is really quite limited in terms of allowing you to tune the way in which it schedules and handles requests. And some of these limitations are a bit obscure... But, of course, that's what allows it to be so fast and scalable...

Answer (score 6):

I don't think your code would work.

The `doGet` method is running in threads managed by the servlet container. When a request comes in, a servlet thread is occupied, and it will not be released until `doGet` method return. In your code, the `executor.submit` would return a `Future` object. To get the actual result you need to invoke `get` method on the `Future` object, and it would block until the `MyTask` finishes its task. Only after that, `doGet` method returns and new requests can kick in.

I am not familiar with GAE, but according to [their docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Requests_and_Servlets), you can declare your servlet as thread-safe and then the container will dispatch multiple requests to each web server in parallel:

```
<!-- in appengine-web.xml -->
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

Answer (score 5):

You implicitly asked two questions, so let me answer both:

**1. How can I get my AppEngine Instance to handle multiple concurrent requests?**

You really only need to do two things:

1. Add the statement `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` to your `appengine-web.xml` file, which you can find in the `war\WEB-INF` folder.
2. Make sure that the code inside **all** your request handlers is actually thread-safe, i.e. use only local variables in your `doGet(...)`, `doPost(...)`, etc. methods or make sure you synchronize all access to class or global variables.

This will tell the AppEngine instance server framework that your code is thread-safe and that you are allowing it to call **all** of your request handlers multiple times in different threads to handle several requests at the same time. Note: AFAIK, It is not possible to set this one a per-servlet basis. So, **ALL** your servlets need to be thread-safe!

So, in essence, the executor-code you posted is already included in the server code of each AppEngine instance, and actually calls your `doGet(...)` method from inside the run method of a separate thread that AppEngine creates (or reuses) for each request.  Basically `doGet()` already *is* your `MyTask()`.

The relevant part of the Docs is here (although it doesn't really say much): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

**2. Is the posted code useful for this (or any other) purpose?**

AppEngine in its current form does not allow you to create and use your own threads to accept requests. It only allows you to create threads *inside* your `doGet(...)` handler, using the `currentRequestThreadFactory()` method you mentioned, but only to do parallel processing for this one request and not to accept a second one in parallel (this happens *outside* `doGet()`).

The name `currentRequestThreadFactory()` might be a little misleading here. It does not mean that it will return the `current` `Factory` of `RequestThreads`, i.e. threads that handle requests. It means that it returns a `Factory` that can create `Threads` inside the `currentRequest`. So, unfortunately it is actually not even allowed to use the returned ThreadFactory beyond the scope of the current `doGet()` execution, like you are suggesting by creating an Executor based on it and keeping it around in a class variable.

For frontend instances, any threads you create inside a `doGet()` call will get terminated immediately when your `doGet()` method returns. For backend instances, you are allowed to create threads that keep running, but since you are not allowed to open server sockets for accepting requests inside these threads, these will still not allow you to manage the request handling yourself.

You can find more details on what you *can* and *cannot* do inside an appengine servlet here:

[The Java Servlet Environment - The Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox) (specifically the *Threads* section)

***For completeness, let's see how your code can be made "legal":***

The following should work, but it won't make a difference in terms of your code being able to handle multiple requests in parallel. That will be determined solely by the `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` setting in you appengine-web.xml. So, technically, this code is just really inefficient and splits an essentially linear program flow across two threads. But here it is anyways:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);

        Future<MyResult> result = executor.submit(new MyTask(request)); // Fires off request handling in a separate thread

        writeResponse(response, result.get()); // Waits for thread to complete and builds response. After that, doGet() returns
    }
}
```

Since you are already inside a separate thread that is specific to the request you are currently handling, you should definitely save yourself the "thread inside a thread" and simply do this instead:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        writeResponse(response, new MyTask(request).call()); // Delegate request handling to MyTask object in current thread and write out returned response
    }
}
```

Or, even better, just move the code from MyTask.call() into the doGet() method. ;)

**Aside - Regarding the limit of 10 simultaneous servlet threads you mentioned:**

This is a (temporary) design-decision that allows Google to control the load on their servers more easily (specifically the memory use of servlets).

You can find more discussion on those issues here:

- [Issue 7927: Allow configurable limit of concurrent requests per instance](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7927)
- [Dynamic Backend Instance Scaling](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/Wvco3AQR-AM/N1Y7S2HfukkJ)
- [If your bill shoots up due to increased latency, you may not be refunded the charges incurred](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/y-LnZ2WYJ5Q/j_w13F4oSSkJ)

This topic has been bugging the heck out of me, too, since I am a strong believer in ultra-lean servlet code, so my usual servlets could easily handle hundreds, if not thousands, of concurrent requests. Having to pay for more instances due to this arbitrary limit of 10 threads per instance is a little annoying to me to say the least. But reading over the links I posted above, it sounds like they are aware of this and are working on a better solution. So, let's see what announcements Google I/O 2013 will bring in May... :)

Answer (score 2):

I second the assessments of *ericson* and *Markus A.*

If however, for some reason (or for some other scenario) you want to follow the path that uses your code snippet as a starting point, I'd suggest that you change your executor definition to:

```
private static Executor executor;
```

so that it becomes static across instances.